# jQuery: cropit to remove image data and replace with a new one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the `cropit.js` jquery plugin to crop images in the browser.
The plugin website is [here](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/).

The issue that I have is that I am loading the images dynamically based on the image that's *clicked* on.

The first image loads fine and everything works perfectly. However, if I click on the second image or any other image, it doesn't load onto the cropper area and the First image always gets stuck in the cropping area for some reason.

I've tried to create a Fiddle to explain this but I think due to some security reasons, the external images wont load using cropit.js. Also, jsfiddle wont allow http: url's so I couldn't get the fiddle up and running. but the structure of my code is this: https://jsfiddle.net/hhshgeed/

You just have to run this locally in a simple html file with all the images available in the same folder as your html file. *Also, you need to include the cropit.js as well.*

This is my entire code:

```
$('.position').live('click', function(){
    var img = $(this).attr('src');
    alert(img);

    // Re-enables the cropper.
    // Does the opposite to `disable` method.
    $(function() {
        $('.image-editor').cropit({
            imageBackground: true,
            imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 20,
            imageState: {
                src: ''+img+'',
            }
         });

         $('.rotate-cw').click(function() {
             $('.image-editor').cropit('rotateCW');
         });

         $('.rotate-ccw').click(function() {
              $('.image-editor').cropit('rotateCCW');
         });

         $('.export').click(function() {
             var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export', {
                 type: 'image/webp',
                 quality: .9,
                 originalSize: true
              });
         });
     });
});
```

As you can see in my code, I'm trying to use the variable `img` in the cropit `src` function. This works but only once.

```
imageState: {
    src: ''+img+'',
}
```

Could someone please advise on this issue as I'm literally banging my head against the wall.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using replace on the src? I have had better results using replace when setting src. image.src = src.replace("old", "new");

Comment: @Mmcgowa3, where do you think I should use the replace() ?

Comment: where you are setting the new class, try replacing the image src with a new instance of the image that has the new class property.

Answer (score 1):

You need to to destroy current instance of **cropit** using - 
`$('.image-editor').cropit('destroy');`

Answer (score -1):

You've wrapped the entire `cropit` code inside of a `$(function() {});` block.  I don't think this is what you want, as that function only fires the first time you click.  You can see it failing by throwing an alert inside that function and clicking a few times; it only fires on the first click.

If you just remove the `$(function() {});` block the rest of your code should fire, which might solve the issue you have.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. the code still fires once!